# How do I log/print query and param for a Dropwizard application?

Tags: dropwizard, jdbi

I'm using @BindBean to bind with the sql query. 
I can see using     "org.skife.jdbi.v2": TRACE would only give me the query with params as "?" Any idea i can print all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log the sql by writing SqlCustomizer.

```
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.StatementContext;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlStatementCustomizer;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlStatementCustomizerFactory;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlStatementCustomizingAnnotation;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.tweak.StatementCustomizer;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@SqlStatementCustomizingAnnotation(LogSqlFactory.Factory.class)
public @interface LogSqlFactory {

    static class Factory implements SqlStatementCustomizerFactory {

        @Override
        public SqlStatementCustomizer createForMethod(Annotation annotation, Class sqlObjectType, Method method) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public SqlStatementCustomizer createForType(Annotation annotation, Class sqlObjectType) {
            return q -> q.addStatementCustomizer(new StatementCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void beforeExecution(PreparedStatement stmt, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
                    System.out.println(stmt.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterExecution(PreparedStatement stmt, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException { }

                @Override
                public void cleanup(StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException { }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public SqlStatementCustomizer createForParameter(Annotation annotation, Class sqlObjectType, Method method, Object arg) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Just include this annotation and use this in SqlObject. In your case use this annotation like this,

```
@LogSqlFactory 
public inteface myinteface{
@SqlQuery("select :c1 from tablename where cond = :cd")
   String returnMeValue(@Bind("c1") String c1, @Bind("cd") Integer cd);
}
```

If you use custom loggers for logging, then beforeExecution method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Dropwizard's DBIFactory? It configures JDBI to log this way out of the box.